# Angular Chrome Extension iframe url gets changed on reloading the frame

Tags: angular, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am creating an chrome extension using Angular in which i am using an iframe to load the angular page. During the initial load it loads the index.html where the angular application checks whether the user is authenticated or not. If not authenticated the route is changed to /login and shows login page in the iframe which works fine.

Initial Request url: `chrome-extension://ejifaedjedcpmdnefibikbokapakjebh/index.html`

When i reload the frame it sends the request url like below

`chrome-extension://ejifaedjedcpmdnefibikbokapakjebh/login` during this time it shows the item has been moved or edited or deleted.

[image]

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "piper",
  "description": "Piper chrome extension",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "/assets/icons/ICON.png",
    "default_title": "Click me!"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "/assets/icons/ICON.png",
    "32": "/assets/icons/ICON.png",
    "48": "/assets/icons/ICON.png",
    "128": "/assets/icons/ICON.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js", "runtime.js", "polyfills.js", "main.js", "scripts.js"],
      "css": ["content.css", "styles.css"]
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "index.html",
        "toolbar.html",
        "toolbar.scss",
        "toolbar.js",
        "/assets/icons/ICON.png",
        "main.ts"
      ],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "use_dynamic_url": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my implementation of iframe in content.js file

```
function injectAngularApplication() {
  var angularApplicationIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  angularApplicationIframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('index.html');
  angularApplicationIframe.id = 'angularApplication';
  angularApplicationIframe.allow = 'clipboard-read; clipboard-write';
  angularApplicationIframe.className = 'angular_application_iframe';

  document.body.appendChild(angularApplicationIframe);
  document.body.style.marginRight = '30%';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the reload issue of iframe.

**Issue**

When we open the index.html from chrome extension in browser it will be **chrome-extension://hhepjhlcooccjdaomokbfbikgmemdlgk/index.html**

and then it routes to the desired page in my case it is login so it redirects like **chrome-extension://hhepjhlcooccjdaomokbfbikgmemdlgk/login** if i do a reload it shows 404 page because browser is trying to go to chrome-extension://hhepjhlcooccjdaomokbfbikgmemdlgk/login straight without loading the /index.html.

**Solution**

1. I have updated the base href in index.html like below

```
<base href="/index.html" />
```

2. Then made the routes to use hash  like below

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```